# Passing Extended Class Method as a Call-Back Function in WordPress

Tags: php, class, wordpress

This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794152/passing-class-method-as-a-call-back-function-in-wordpress). When the class is extended, it refers to the original class method. The echoed class name in the created page should be *AnotherAdminPage* which is the extended class name.

```
/* 
    Plugin Name: static method callback demo
*/

class AnotherAdminPage extends AdminPageClass {
}

add_action('admin_menu', AnotherAdminPage::_admin_menu());

class AdminPageClass {

    static function _admin_menu() {
        $class_name = get_class();
        $classinstance = new $class_name();
        return array(&$classinstance, "admin_menu");
    }
    function admin_menu() {
        add_options_page(
            'Sample Admin Page Class', 
            'Sample Admin Page Class', 
            'manage_options',
            'sample_admin-page_class', 
            array(&$this, 'admin_page'));
    }
    function admin_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <p><?php echo get_class(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

It works by redefining the methods in the extended class but it becomes somewhat pointless to extend it in that case.

```
class AnotherAdminPage extends AdminPageClass {

    static function _admin_menu() {
        $class_name = get_class();
        $classinstance = new $class_name();
        return array(&$classinstance, "admin_menu");
    }   
    function admin_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <p><?php echo get_class(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }   
}
```

So is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it by myself that this works.

```
/* 
    Plugin Name: extended class method as a callback demo
*/

class AnotherAdminPage extends AdminPageClass {
}

add_action('admin_menu', array(new AnotherAdminPage, "admin_menu"));

class AdminPageClass {

    function admin_menu() {
        add_options_page(
            'Sample Admin Page Class', 
            'Sample Admin Page Class', 
            'manage_options',
            'sample_admin_page_class', 
            array(&$this, 'admin_page'));
    }
    function admin_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <p><?php echo get_class($this); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }   
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer since you don't use static function anymore

Comment: So it is an issue related to static scope. Thanks for mentioning it. But this way, the extended class seems to refer to the own instance. This is what I wanted. But the strange thing is that without redefining the `msg()` method, it refers to the original.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-called-class.php) (PHP 5.3)

**EDIT** :

If you don't have PHP 5.3, you should read this

[PHP get_called_class() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498510/php-get-called-class-alternative)

Comment: Thanks for your input. One of the servers I'm using has the PHP version of 5.2.17. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Thanks. So it's not possible with v5.2.x. I found a workaround by the way. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use get **get_called_class** instead of **get_class**. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php . Then you don't need to redefine the _admin_menu function

Comment: Hmm, the PHP version of one of the server I'm using is 5.2.17, which is a free shared host. Thanks for the input.